# Why isn't SMART hard drive data showing up in SpeedFan?

Tags: hard-drive

I use SpeedFan for it's "S.M.A.R.T." tab and the ability to check the health of my hard drives. Used it a several machines in the past but on the newest one I have there are no hard disks listed. Is it because I have an SSD drive now? Is that known to cause problems? I checked the BIOS and the SMART option is on.

Answer (score 1):

Some controllers don't seem to be supported, I have the same issue here.

Comment: You mean the controller on the motherboard?

Comment: Yes. I guess that SpeedFan doesn't support some...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the program as an administrator.

Simply right click on the program and start it with "Run as administrator."

Comment: I'll try that out . . . but it seems to have more to do with driver/motherboard support.